# validate object with empty parentheses in protobuf

Tags: json, scala, protobuf-java

I have a json file converted to protobuf format with empty parentheses in some object. Could you help me identify empty objects in protobuf (first case)? I tried to use bytes size but for a good object the size is 0 like an empty.

load data

```
val json = // readFromJson
val protobufBuilder = Converted.newBuilder()
JsonFormat.parser.ignoringUnknownFields.merge(json, protobufBuilder)
val converted = protobufBuilder.build()
```

1. 

input

```
{
“a”: 0,
“someObject”: {}
}
```

scala code

```
println(converted.hasSomeObject)  // true
converted.getSomeObjectBytes.size() // 0
```

2. 

input

```
{
“a”: 0,
“someObject”: {
    “type”: 1,
    “name”: “”Jack
}
}
```

scala

```
println(converted.hasSomeObject)  // true
converted.getSomeObjectBytes.size() // 0
```

3. 

input

```
{
“a”: 0
}
```

scala

```
println(converted.hasSomeObject)  // false
converted.getSomeObjectBytes.size() // 0
```

Comment: Where is the protobuf data? This all looks like JSON.

Comment: Added code with converting